# New to Python/Kivy - Why am I getting 'cannot import name 'MDLabel' from 'kivy.uix.label' error'?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'MDLabel' from 'kivy.uix.label' (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\label.py)
```

Hi, Im very new to python and Im having this error while programing in Python and I dont know what else to do

```
import kivy
import kivy.app
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
from kivy.uix.label import MDLabel


class FirstApp(kivy.app.App):

    def build(self):
        return kivy.uix.label.Label(text = "HI world")
    
FirstApp().run()
```

I tried solving using the label type and it didnt work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  From https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/label/index.html, it looks like it's ```from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel```.